# Python 3.6 import cv2 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, opencv

When I try to `import cv2`, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
   from .cv2 import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Check your `sys.path`. In one of the listed directories you should find your module.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [doc](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html):

**1.** Download latest OpenCV release from [sourceforge site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/) and double-click to extract it.

**2.** Go to **opencv/build/python/2.7** folder.

**3.** Copy **cv2.pyd** to **C:/Python27/lib/site-packages**.

**4.** Open Python IDLE and type following codes in Python terminal:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
```

Comment: No such directory exists in OpenCV 3.1.0 nor 4.0.0-alpha obtained at https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was related with missing dll in the os, related with multimedia part of windows server essentials, as per https://jakubmertl.com/blog/python-import-cv2-error

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you.
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv
Download opencv from above link and run command

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.4.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Python 3.7 /IDLE on  Windows 7. I ran `cmd` to get to DOS. Entering

```
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install opencv-python
```

did the trick.

See this

[Getting started with OpenCV and Python](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/simple-operations-on-images-using-opencv-d37b26e6e3ab)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove dot before cv2.
It should be:

> from cv2 import *